# laravel 5 subdomain and authentication

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have set the `config/session.php` into `'domain' => '.stage.myproj.com',`.

here is my problem, whenever I log-in a user in `stage.myproj.com`, it cannot be authenticat on its subdomain `username.stage.myproj.com`. any idea?

my `routes.php` i got this code:

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth', 'domain' => '{alias}.'stage.myproj.com'], function($alias) {
                Route::get('dashboard', 'DashController@index');

...
```

in my `DashController.php` I got this one:

```
public function index($alias = null)
{
$auth_account = \App\Account::where( 'alias', 'LIKE', $alias )->get();
            if ( $auth_account->count() < 1 ) {
                return Redirect::to('/');
            }
Extras::cview( 'dash', compact( $default ), true );
}
```